# How to add filters to OpenCover tool to skip some of the classes in a namespace

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

How can I add filters to skip some of the classes in a namespace/assembly. For example: `SYM.UI` is the base assembly and i want to skip `SYM.UI.ViewModels`. Writing the below filter but it is including all of them and not fulfilling my request:

```
+[SYM.UI*]* -[SYM.UI.ViewModels*]*
```

Kindly help me correcting this?

Comment: i have tried using like below +[SYM.UI*]* -[SYM.UI]ViewModels* but still no luck. advise

Comment: adding for future readers: You should have an explicit filter "+[ * ]*" always present as a catchall, for case of **providing only exclusion list in filter**. If you are not providing "+[ * ]*" for this case then no code coverage report will be generated.

Answer (score 28):

The [opencover wiki](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/wiki/Usage) is a good place to start.

The usage is described as +/-[modulefilter]typefilter (this is based on how you would see the types in IL; where the type filter also includes the namespace and module filter usually is the name of the assembly (without the file extension).

Thus to exclude your types you could use

```
+[SYM.UI]* -[SYM.UI]SYM.UI.ViewModels.*
```

NOTE: Exclusion filters take preference over inclusion filters.

Comment: There is also some packaged documentation with OpenCover which is worth a read as it is more up to date than the wiki (I am not a wiki person)

Answer (score 4):

You can use following:

```
"-filter:+[*]* -[SYM.UI]SYM.UI.ViewModels.*"
```

Note that the quotes must be around the `-filter:` part, too